# Will the MacBook Pro hinge tighten over time or with use?

Tags: macbook-pro

The hinge on my 5 month old MacBook Pro is very loose. I took it to the Apple store, where I was told that it will tighten over time. Has anyone else had the same problem? Has the hinge tightened over time? This sounds suspect, due to the fact he said the spring inside gets tighter, but I was taught in school that springs lose their tension over time.

Comment: Take it back… that's not normal and as far as I know doesn't get tightened but loosen.

Comment: Shame on whoever told you it would tighten. If it tightened with use, it would get to a point where you couldn't open (or close) your lid without breaking the hinge. Instead you just (eventually) get a lid that won't stay open except at it's extremity states.

Comment: He said this and I was still like hmmm... you are breaking the laws of physics here. But he could replicate the error I showed with the hinge at the genius bar then took the laptop apart at the back and found nothing wrong with it as he couldn't replicate it after me and him both doing it. BTW the apple store in question is the Solihull store in the UK with a guy named Josh ( in the genius bar). Yes I am prepared to name and shame this person, where can I find an email address to complain at apple?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not tighten overtime. If anything, it can only become looser as it wears (simple physics).

You should book an appointment with a Genius at the Apple Store and tell them you are unhappy with it. They will either replace the mechanism or give you a new machine.

The previous person you dealt with, unfortunately gave you false information.

Comment: I thought this. Unfortunately I'm going back to University and the nearest Apple Store is £30 on the train :/.

Comment: Call 1-800-MY-APPL and speak with a CSR. I called them a long time asking about dust between the digitizer and the screen on my iPhone 3G. The CST said it was covered under warranty. I got it replaced (the tech at the store said it *wasn't* covered but would do it this one time). He did a poor job. I called and they passed me to a specialist. He pulled up the order and found out the tech's name, and said he would "educate" him. I went back and saw the same guy. They definitely talked to him because he apologized and said he would keeping putting in screens till I was happy